# Creating a new column

Tags: excel, powerbi

I need to create a new column from a column containing customer comments.

The goal is to apply conditions on a number of words in the comments to create the terms of the new column.
For example, when we find the word "cancel" in the comment column we get the modality "Cancel" in the new column.
For example, if we find the word "balance" in the comment column we get the modality "balance request", and so on:

[image]

Comment: What if your column has multiple key words?  How many key words might you have?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use nested if statement (this is case-sensitive):

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"YourLastStep", "NewColumnName", each if Text.Contains([SourceTextColumn], "cancel") then "Cancel" else if Text.Contains([SourceTextColumn], "request") then "Request" else "None")
```